# How immediatly return accumulator from foldLeft

Tags: scala

How optimize following code in good, functional way?

```
  List(1,2,3,4,5).foldLeft(0) {
    case (acc, e) =>
      if(acc > 5) acc
      else acc + e
  }
```

It is of course simple example, I am asking for general way, how do not iterate all collection if we known that accumulator will not change

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using `@tailrec` instead of `foldLeft`:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec
def methodOption1(values: List[Int])(acc: Int): Int = {
  if(acc > 5 || values.isEmpty) acc
  else method(values.tail)(acc + values.head)
}

@tailrec
def methodOption2(values: List[Int])(sum: Int): Int = {
  values match {
    case Nil => sum
    case _ if sum > 5 => sum
    case e :: tail => method(tail)(sum + e)
  }
}
methodOption1(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))(0)
methodOption2(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))(0)
```

You also can make Mapper to "view" it as .foldLeft

```
implicit class ListMapper[A](xs: List[A]) {
 def foldLeftAsTailRecWithStop[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B)(stop: B => Boolean): B = {
    @tailrec
    def tailrec(xs: List[A])(acc: B): B = {
      if(xs.isEmpty || stop(acc)) acc
      else tailrec(xs.tail)(op(acc, xs.head))
    }
    tailrec(xs)(z)
  }
  
  def foldLeftAsTailRec[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
    @tailrec
    def tailrec(xs: List[A])(acc: B): B = {
      if(xs.isEmpty) acc
      else tailrec(xs.tail)(op(acc, xs.head))
    }
    tailrec(xs)(z)
  }
}

List(1, 2, 3,4,5).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
List(1, 2, 3,4,5).foldLeftAsTailRec(0)(_ + _)
List(1, 2, 3,4,5).foldLeftAsTailRecWithStop(0)(_ + _)(_ > 5)
```

Outputs:

```
res0: Int = 15
res1: Int = 15
res2: Int = 6
```

Comment: This is not doing the same operation as the original code. The `>5` test is on the accumulated value, not the current element. And it would be `takeWhile` not `filterNot`.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the notice, I thought he is checking the curr value and not the acc - Edited.

Comment: Thanks for response, I've thought about tail recursion but but I was wondering if i can use some kind of dedicated method (like foldLeft).

Comment: Other answers show how this can be done with dedicated methods, but I strongly suggest that you get comfortable with writing this sort of thing as a recursive function because it is often the cleanest and fastest solution.

Comment: Is there a reason to use curried versions of the recursive method rather than just two arguments?

Comment: @Tim - You mean with `(_ > 5)`? - No, just though it will look nicer, there any side-effects that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I means `(values: List[Int])(acc: Int)` rather than the more usual `(values: List[Int], acc: Int)`

Comment: @Tim Is there a specific reason not to use the curried version? I mean convention and etc, can you please elaborate?

Comment: The main reason for currying is to allow partial application and to improve type inference. If neither of these are required then the convention is to use the uncurried form for clarity and efficiency.

Comment: Wdym by “partial application and to improve type inference”? can you please eloberate?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`scanLeft`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html#scanLeft%5BB%5D(z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.LazyList%5BB%5D)(*produces a lazy list containing cumulative results of applying the operator going left to right, including the initial value*) and [`find`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option%5BA%5D) (*finds the first element of the lazy list satisfying a predicate, if any*):

```
 List(1,2,3,4,5)
  .to(LazyList) 
  .scanLeft(0)(_ + _)
  .find(_ > 5) // Some(6): Option[Int]
```

**UPD**

To tackle the issue raised by [@jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh) in the comments I was able to come up only with this ugly design:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5)
  .to(LazyList)
  .scanLeft((0, 0))((t, c) => (t._1 + c, t._1)) // aggregate contains current and previous value
  .takeWhile(t => (t._1 > 5 && t._2 <= 5) || t._1 <= 5)
  .last._1
```

So I would say that writing custom `tailrec` function as in [@Zvi Mints](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10875851/zvi-mints)'s answer should be a better option here.

Comment: For `List(1,2,1)` this returns `None` instead of the expected `4`.

Comment: @jwvh yep, missed that.